# Doctrine DBAL - WHERE IN array with additional parameter

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dbal

Using the example docs, I was able to get a query like this to work.

```
SELECT
f.foo,
b.bar
FROM Foo f
LEFT JOIN Bar b
WHERE 
f.foo = 20
AND b.bar IN ?
```

Using DBAL, this code returns results.

```
$result = $this->connection->executeQuery(
            $SQL,
            array($bar_array),
            array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)
        )->fetchAll();
```

I would like to search for f.foo as a single integer parameter well as looking for the IN statement, but I haven't figured out how to get it to function, since all of the example documents have the array as the only parameter.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The params and types are parallel arrays. All you should have to do is add your placeholder for the f.foo value and add in the correct PDO type in types argument.

```
$SQL = "SELECT f.foo, b.bar
        FROM Foo f LEFT JOIN Bar b
        WHERE  f.foo = ? AND b.bar IN (?)";

$result = $this->connection
    ->executeQuery($SQL, array($foo, $bar_array),array(
            \PDO::PARAM_INT,
            \Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType::INTEGER
     ))->fetchAll();
```

You can [read](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion) the manual for more information.

Comment: If you read this around 2024, replace `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY` with `\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType::INTEGER`.
At least that's how it works in `doctrine/dbal:3.7.1`, but I didn't check in which version exactly they changed it.

Answer (score 30):

I just encountered the below behavior, so I am writing it here, maybe it will prove useful for someone else.

Beware when using named parameters with IN. You will have to repeat the names for the type-array as well:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name IN (:param_array)";

$stmt = $this->db->executeQuery(
        $sql,
        [
            'param_array' => $paramArray
        ],
        [
            'param_array' => Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY
        ]
    );
```

Comment: The above thankfully works fine now, since at least DBAL 2.6 (possibly earlier)

Comment: Thanx, man! I spend 3 hours trying to achieve this. whit no success.